# What are best practices when implementing an enum in Java?

Tags: java, serialization, enums

When implementing an enum, should we take care of its serialization or Standard Java takes care of it? 
Another point concerns the null safety, how can we make sure that enums are null safe?

Comment: What do you mean by *"make sure that enums are null safe"*? When you access an enum constant, it's never `null`.

Comment: Perhaps if you post some code it will give a clearer idea of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Java already handles enum serialisation specially. Nothing you need to do. Define 'null safety'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enum defines *constants*. This means that at compile time you know all possible values of certain type and you enumerate it in an *enum* data type.

```
public enum Day {
    SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY,
    THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY 
}
```

This doesn't mean that you cannot have something like this:

```
Day today = null;
```

Enum implements Serializable then it is Serializable and the default implementation of `toString()` returns the name of the constant.

For some more information, please refer to [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)